# Check whether the map $f(z)={z\over e^z-1}$ is open or not in $\{z|$Im$(z)>0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity, open-map

As per open mapping theorem, a holomorphic, non-constant function on a region is an open map.
Here the domain $\Omega=\{z\in\Bbb{C}|\operatorname{Im}(z)>0\}$ is a region, $f$ is non-constant. 
Here $f$ has removable singularities at the points $2k\pi i$, $k\in\Bbb{Z}$, since it can be easily shown that $\lim_{z\to2k\pi i}(z-2k\pi i)f(z)=0\ \forall k\in\Bbb{Z}$.
So, can I use open mapping theorem here? Thanks for the assistance in advance.

Comment: Your function has simple *poles* at $z=2 k \pi i$, not removable singularities. Your claim that $\lim_{z\to2k\pi i}(z-2k\pi i)f(z)=0$  is wrong.

Comment: ${z\over e^z-1}={1\over \sum_{n\ge0}{z^n\over (n+1)!}}\ \forall z\in\Bbb{C}$. Then $\lim_{z\to2k\pi i}{z\over e^z-1}={1\over \sum_{n\ge0}{(2k\pi i)^n\over (n+1)!}}\ne0$. So, $\lim_{z\to2k\pi i}(z-2k\pi i)f(z)=(2k\pi i-2k\pi i){1\over \sum_{n\ge0}{(2k\pi i)^n\over (n+1)!}}=0$. Is it wrong?

Comment: @qbert $2k\pi i$ are also poles of $f$ and they are inside the given domain for $k\in\mathbb{N}$. So $f$ is not holomorphic in the upper half-plane.

Comment: @JohnThompson yes I was dumb and swapped the axes, forgot to delete my comment

Comment: Get any answer?